# Automate google play search items in a list

Tags: python, function, web-scraping, automation, web-crawler

I am working on a python project where I need to find out what are the apps that the company owns. 
For example, I have a list:

```
company_name = ['Airbnb', 'WeFi']
```

I would like to write a python function/ program to do the following:

1 . have it **automatically** search item in the list in Play store

2 . if the company name match,even if it only matches the first name, eg "Airbnb" will match "Airbnb,inc"

[image: Airbnb Search Page circled]

3. Then it will click into the page and read its category
   [image: Airbnb Read category]
4. If the company has more than one app, it will do the same for all apps.
5. each app information of the company is store in `tuple = {app name, category}`
6. Desired end result will be a list of tuples

eg:

```
print(company_name[0])
print(type(company_name[0]))
```

outcome:
airbnb
tuple

```
print(company_name[0][0])
```

outcome:
[('airbnb','Travel')]

This is a mixed of many knowledge and I am a newbie to python. So please give me some direction of how should I start writing the code.

I learn selenium could do automate "load more" function but I am not sure what exactly package I could use?

Comment: Do you have code to scrape one page?

Comment: Yes I know how to scrape the Google page.but I have trouble doing the 'automate' part. I have no idea how to do automate search item in list and automate click into page.

Comment: Add your code that gets you that far

Comment: I used beautifulsoup and urllib.request to do so. I'll upload the code tonight after I got home! Thanks!

Comment: No worries, I will have a look when you do

Comment: Hi @PadraicCunningham , Thanks for trying to help! my code is much less sophisticated than Peter's. I wish to study his code first. I will post my code when there are further problems! Thanks again!!

Comment: it is always good to supply your code when you ask a question, if you are going to use bs4, there are much simpler ways to get what you want, also I thought there was an issue with pagination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written a little demo that may help you to achieve your goal. I used requests and Beautiful Soup. It's not exactly what you wanted but it can be adapted easily.

```
import requests
import bs4

company_name = "airbnb"
def get_company(company_name):
    r = requests.get("https://play.google.com/store/search?q="+company_name)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    subtitles = soup.findAll("a", {'class':"subtitle"})
    dev_urls = []
    for title in subtitles:
        try:
            text = title.attrs["title"].lower()
        #Sometimes there is a subtitle without any text on GPlay
        #Catchs the error
        except KeyError:
            continue
        if company_name in text:
            url = "https://play.google.com" + title.attrs["href"]
            dev_urls.append(url)
    return dev_urls

def get_company_apps_url(dev_url):
    r = requests.get(dev_url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    titles = soup.findAll("a", {"class":"title"})
    return ["https://play.google.com"+title.attrs["href"] for title in titles]

def get_app_category(app_url):
    r = requests.get(app_url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    developer_name = soup.find("span", {"itemprop":"name"}).text
    app_name = soup.find("div", {"class":"id-app-title"}).text
    category = soup.find("span", {"itemprop":"genre"}).text
    return (developer_name, app_name, category)

dev_urls = get_company("airbnb")
apps_urls = get_company_apps_url(dev_urls[0])
get_app_category(apps_urls[0])

>>> get_company("airbnb")
['https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Airbnb,+Inc']
>>> get_company_apps_url("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Airbnb,+Inc")
['https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.airbnb.android']
>>> get_app_category("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.airbnb.android")
('Airbnb, Inc', 'Airbnb', 'Travel & Local')
```

My script with google

```
dev_urls = get_company("google")
apps_urls = get_company_apps_url(dev_urls[0])
for app in apps_urls:
    print(get_app_category(app))

('Google Inc.', 'Google Duo', 'Communication')
('Google Inc.', 'Google Translate', 'Tools')
('Google Inc.', 'Google Photos', 'Photography')
('Google Inc.', 'Google Earth', 'Travel & Local')
('Google Inc.', 'Google Play Games', 'Entertainment')
('Google Inc.', 'Google Calendar', 'Productivity')
('Google Inc.', 'YouTube', 'Media & Video')
('Google Inc.', 'Chrome Browser - Google', 'Communication')
('Google Inc.', 'Google Cast', 'Tools')
('Google Inc.', 'Google Sheets', 'Productivity')
```

Comment: hi @Peter234, this is great! You provided a new perspective to approach my problem. I will take a deep look into it!!  Thanks again!!

Comment: I just wanted to now from the down voter what the problem is with my answer. Am I not supposed to post so much code?

Comment: @Peter234 Don't pay attention to single downvotes. If there're a couple of them, it's time to make an action, otherwise just ignore. Some people are just a bit more crazy than others :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option to search google play programmatically:
https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper/#list

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');

gplay.list({
    category: gplay.category.GAME_ACTION,
    collection: gplay.collection.TOP_FREE,
    num: 2
  })
  .then(console.log, console.log);
```

(it's nodejs, not python though)